# Athena query engine 2 Error Query cancelled! : Bytes scanned limit was exceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-athena

recently our AWS Athena engine is upgarded to Engine 2. So when we execute a query, which was running fine in Engine 1 is resulting into below error. When I did some research (google), I got to know that it may be due to per query data scan limit, but that was same in Engine 1 as well and we were able to query just fine. I had gone through the Engine 2 upgrade doc and there is no breaking change specified for this kind of error. If any of you ran into the same issue and/or you are aware of this, any inputs are very much appreciated. Thank you.

**Query cancelled! : Bytes scanned limit was exceeded**

Comment: How big is the data source (all files) referenced by the query? Does it fail for _every_ query, or just that one? Are your data files compressed / partitioned / columnar?

Comment: the workgroup config might have changed when you switched to version 2 . Can you verify if there is any limit set on it https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/workgroups-setting-control-limits-cloudwatch.html#configure-control-limit-per-query ?